# Why does Vault by HashiCorp require the ipc_lock capability to be enabled?

Tags: linux, docker, linux-kernel, hashicorp-vault

Why does Vault by HashiCorp require the ipc_lock capability to be enabled?

Comment: It uses the `mlock` syscall.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's required for this server config option: https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration/index.html#disable_mlock

It uses the mlock syscall which blocks process memory from being swapped to disk. By default this is enabled as you want to avoid swapping your Vault memory onto unencrypted disk.

Usually that capability comes up when running Vault within a container, which I believe allows the container to access the mlock syscall without escalating privileges.

Answer (score 0):

be aware that if you have custom plugins it will probably not load them with mlock enabled.